# Generalization of the L^p space?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces, polish-spaces

I've recently had a look at [https://helios2.mi.parisdescartes.fr/~jdedecke/p1.pdf](https://helios2.mi.parisdescartes.fr/%7Ejdedecke/p1.pdf) . In chapter 3, Definition 3.1, they defined: For any $p \geq 1$, let $\mathbb{L}^p$ be the class of real-valued function of $(\mathcal{X},P)$ ($\mathcal{X}$ is a Polish space and $P$ is a (probability) measure) such that $\lVert f \rVert_p^p := P(\lvert f \rvert^p)$ is finite.

My question: Is the definition of the $\lVert \cdot \rVert_p$-norm equivalent to the normal one, i.e. does it hold that $(P(\lvert f \rvert^p))^{1/p}= (\mathbb{E}(\lvert f \rvert^p))^{1/p}$? Is the class $\mathbb{L}^p$ the same as the $\mathcal{L}^p$ spaces? (I think the difference ist, that $\mathcal{L}^p$ are measurable functions, but not necessarily real-valued and otherwise $\mathbb{L}^p$ are real-valued but not necessarily measurable functions). Or if not, are there cases where they coincide?

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: The norms, and their space $\mathbb L^p$ and the usual $L^p$, are the same. $L^p$ is the quotient of $\mathcal L^p$ by the equivalence relation: "equal a.e."

Comment: Thanks for answering! But $\mathcal{L}^p$ are only measurable functions, aren't they? How can it be the same if $\mathbb{L}^p$ are just real-valued functions that are not explicitly required to be measurable? Or does it follow from $P(\lvert f \rvert^p) < \infty$?

Comment: $\mathcal L^p$ are not "only measurable functions". They are (real or complex valued, depending on the authors) measurable functions such that $\int |f|^pd\mu<\infty$ (I write $\mu$ for $\mathbb P$). And the (equivalence classes) in $\mathbb L^p$ are (classes of) the same functions (they must be assumed to be measurable, otherwise $\int |f|^pd\mu$ is not defined).

Comment: Thanks again. I see that my problem was the equality of $P(\vert f \vert^p) = \int \lvert f \rvert^p dP$, but with this we implicitly assume the functions to be measurable if I understand it right. But I think I got it now, thanks. :)